# How to integrate a Java Project in a Dynamic Webproject

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I have two Java Projects. One is a normal Java Project. I want to integrate this Java Project in my dynamic webproject. That works fine at first. I can easily integrate the project over the Java Build Path. 
But if i call "MyClass" from the dynamic Web Project I always get this exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/project/MyClass
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
>       org.apache.jsp.api_jsp._jspService(api_jsp.java:91)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

This probably means that the other normal javaproject deployed to the Server.

Comment: How are you building your war? (manually, eclipse, other ide?)

Comment: I am deploying the project automatically with eclipse "Run on Server".
There i am able to choose my Tomcat server and it is deployed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the `Dynamic Web Project` -> `Properties` -> `Deployment Assembly` -> `Add` -> `Project` -> `The None Dynamic Web Project`.

This will bundle the other eclipse porject automatically into the WARs lib folder.